# Künneth theorem for compactly supported cohomology of manifold.

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

I know the Künneth theorem for ordinary cohomology of a manifold. Is there any version for the compactly supported cohomology (over Rational) of manifolds. If we take the product of real projective plane with Euclidean Plane then what is the 
compactly supported cohomology (over Rational) of this product?